# downloading a csv from firebase storage as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, firebase, dataframe, google-cloud-platform

I have a `csv` file named `data.csv` on my firebase storage. I am using the following code to access it which downloads the file on my local machine. Is there a way to read the `csv` files as `pandas dataframe` directly? (without having to download it locally)

```
bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)
blob = bucket.blob("app_data/data.csv")
blob.download_to_filename("my_data_file.csv")
```

Comment: Hi @Karvy1, I have posted answer. Can you check if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read the file from Firebase Storage directly into pandas dataframe. Firebase Storage stores files in Google Cloud Storage. You can make use of the [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) method to directly read the file into pandas dataframe using the file URI in the Google Cloud Storage bucket, which is the same as the URI of the file in Firebase Storage . A sample code for that is the following -

**read.py**

```
import pandas as pd
def panda_csv():
  #please change the file's URI
  data = pd.read_csv('gs://bucket-name/file.csv')
  print (data)

panda_csv()
```

**requirement.txt**

```
pandas==0.24.2
gcsfs==0.2.3
```